# Shopping Cart Shipping Methods are Unavailable

Tags: magento-1.9, soap, soap-api-v2

I have to set shipping method to shopping cart , and i am able to display all the available shipping methods , and I have given valid shipping method as the input parameter to SOAP web service method **"shoppingCartShippingMethod"** so for this, Is there any need to change configuration at the Magento Admin Panel?

```
<?php
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');

$sessionId = $proxy->login('cats', 'sudhir123');
echo "\nSession Id = ";
var_dump($sessionId);

$cartId = $proxy->shoppingCartCreate($sessionId, '3');
echo "\nCart Id = ";
var_dump($cartId);

$customerData = array(
"firstname" => "testFirstname",
"lastname" => "testLastName",
"email" => "testEmail@mail.com",
"mode" => "guest",
"website_id" => "0"
  );
$resultCustomerSet = $proxy->shoppingCartCustomerSet($sessionId, $cartId, $customerData);
echo "\nCustomer Set to Shopping Cart = ";
var_dump($resultCustomerSet);

$customeraddress = $proxy->shoppingCartCustomerAddresses($sessionId,     $cartId, array(array(
'mode' => 'billing',
'firstname' => 'Sudhir',
'lastname' => 'Belagali',
'street' => 'street address',
'city' => 'city',
'region' => 'region',
'postcode' => 'postcode',
'country_id' => 'US',
'telephone' => '123456789',
'is_default_billing' => 1
)));   
echo "\nCustomer Address Set to Shopping Cart = ";
var_dump($customeraddress);

$shoppingcartproduct = $proxy->shoppingCartProductAdd($sessionId,    $cartId, array(array(
'product_id' => '917',
'sku' => 'cricketbat',
'qty' => '5',
'options' => null,
'bundle_option' => null,
'bundle_option_qty' => null,
'links' => null
)));   
echo "\nProduct has been added to cart = ";
var_dump($shoppingcartproduct);


$cartInfo = $proxy->shoppingCartInfo($sessionId, $cartId);
echo "\nCart Information for this Cart Id is ( ".$cartId." )";
var_dump($cartInfo);


$result = $proxy->shoppingCartShippingList($sessionId, $cartId);   
echo "\nAvailable Shipping methods = ";
var_dump($result);
?>
```

[image]

Comment: Try to add a product into the cart

Comment: Product can be added to cart , But i am trying soap to check the available shipping methods , it is giving me an Empty array

Comment: But if you add somethig to cart, are the methods available or still empty?

Comment: With nothing in your cart no shipping methods will be displayed if you access the data via the cart framework

Comment: i have added product information , customer information and customer address information into cart , But still i am unable to set the shipping method to cart

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the System > Configuration > Shipping Methods > "Show Method if Not Applicable" to Yes from the default "No" in the Magento Admin Panel.

[image]

Comment: s sir , it gives us the list of available shipping methods and I still unable to set the shipping method to currently existed cart

Comment: Please post that as a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes even I used to face this problem... Try doing this, it worked in my case:

[SOAP REFERENCE - CART.CREATE](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/checkout/cart/cart.create.html)
From create cart, to add product to cart, to set customer to cart, adding address to cart everything, include a paramater named "store_id".. I know it is not properly shown for SOAP v2 for many of the SOAP calls.. But you can take reference from SOAP v1 and add this parameter like this below for all cases:

First of all to get store-id: do the following on the top of your code, I think you might be using this file out of magento environment keeping it in the root directory of magento..

> require_once ("app/Mage.php");
>
> umask(0);
>
> Mage::app();
>
> $url = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB);
>
> session_start();
>
> Mage::getSingleton("core/session", array("name" => "frontend"));
>
> $storeid = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();

Now use this store-id to in following calls like this:

> $result = $proxy->shoppingCartCreate($sessionId,$storeid);
>
> $result = $proxy->shoppingCartProductAdd($sessionId, $quote_id, array(array(
>   'product_id' => $product_id,
>   'sku' => $sku,
>   'qty' => $qty,
>   'options' => null,
>   )),$storeid);
>
> $resultCustomerSet = $proxy->shoppingCartCustomerSet($sessionId, $result, 
>   $customerData,$storeid);
>
> $result = $client->shoppingCartCustomerAddresses($session, $cart_id, $address,$storeid);

Now try to make this call :

> $result = $client->shoppingCartShippingList($session, $cart_id,$storeid);

I am sure it will return you the shipping addresses.

Also, make sure you give same country in your address for which you have kept the shipping method enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
// get list of shipping methods

$resultShippingMethods = $proxy->shoppingCartShippingList($sessionId, array($shoppingCartId))

// set shipping method

$randShippingMethodIndex = rand(0, count($resultShippingMethods)-1 );
$shippingMethod = $resultShippingMethods[$randShippingMethodIndex]["code"];

$resultShippingMethod = $proxy->shoppingCartShippingMethod($sessionId,  array($shoppingCartId), $shippingMethod);
```

Comment: S sir I tried this , But didnt worked for me

Comment: If you make a checkout normally, the shipping method is showing?

Comment: It is showing me in the website only,,  But not showing me through SOAP call